# plist and TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, plist

Houston, I have a problem, which I am working on for 5 days and cant fix it: So, I am working on an app which has `tabBarController`. On the first tab, there is a `tableViewController` with some objects in it. And when I press a `cell`, I turn to form with a button in it. And when I press this button, it saves the title of `navigationBar` which is on the top (so, it saves a title of cell which you pressed). Then, when I turn to another (second) tab, we can see a view with `tableView` in it. And what I expecting to see in a cell is that title of navBar(or cell) from the first tab. BUT instead, I see in this tableView ALL the objects from the first tableView, but not that one I saved.

Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/1501328

So again: First tab has a tableViewController. When I press a random cell, I move to another view with button on it. When I press the button I save the title of navBar, so its the same as cell name which I tapped. And when I move to second tab, I can see a view with tableview in it and I want to see a saved title in a cell but I see ALL the Objects from the first tab tableView.

I despair, please, help me stackoverflow community ! ! !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you got the same content in the two table views is most probably because they share the same `dataSource`.

If the same object is meant to be the dataSource of two (or more) table views, then you must make the difference in delegate and datasource methods (using the `tableView` parameter).
Check if the title information is stored at the right place, and then double check delegate and datasource methods and ensure they make the difference between the table views when returning number of rows and cells.

If not, then set the appropriate `delegate` and `dataSource` for the table views that displays wrong values.

When looking at the code, only `Favorites` is conforming to delegate and datasource protocols,  is this object the delegate and datasource for both tables ? Nothing in these methods take care of the difference...

Comment: Thanks Vince! To tell the truth, I didn't think about it. But could you tell me please, how can I check if they have the same dataSource and how can I make the difference in delegate and datasource methods?

Comment: all these methods provide a first parameter, of type `UITableView *`, which is the table view asking for the info.. example : `(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`. Make the difference with the `tableView` reference. To check if they have same datasource and/or delegate, I would say you must know it, because you set them, iether in IB, or in your code...

Comment: You're welcome, was answering the previous one, when you decided to delete it ;)

Comment: Haha, really? I was thinking that it was totally lost :)